# Countif True/False values for alternating rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I automate my scoring formula to count odd rows as `1` for `TRUE` and even rows as `1` for `FALSE`?

## Backstory

I'm trying to import a quiz that I found in the back of an ancient, eldritch tome into G Sheets. The order of the questions is fixed - the notes in the margins are **very** specific that a "dire fate" awaits anyone who "dares disturb these ancient mysteries." So I'm putting the questions in G Sheets in order, but in order to count the scores, I need to have every odd row give +1 if the answer is `TRUE` and every even row give +1 if the answer is `FALSE`.

| Row Number | Question | Answer | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dread Cthulhu is my personal Lord and Slayer | TRUE | 1 |
| 2 | Men are destined to master their own fates | FALSE | 1 |
| 3 | This way is madness | TRUE | 0 |
| 4 | These secrets should have stayed buried | FALSE | 0 |

I know I could brute force this with addition, such as

`=COUNTIF(C2,TRUE)+COUNTIF(C4,TRUE)+COUNTIF(C6,TRUE)...`

but every minute I spend typing, I feel the tendrils of existential dread gnawing at the foundations of my soul. Plus, that sounds super-boring.

So, is there a way to automate having `COUNTIF()` (or `COUNTIFS()`) do this for me?

### Things That I Have Tried or Thought About

- `ROW()`, but it doesn't seem to play nice with `COUNTIFS()`, just gives me a `0`.

`=COUNTIFS(C2:C666,TRUE,A2:A666,ISEVEN(ROW)`

- Adding a cheater-column that does this for me with `ROW()`, but I'm worried that tinkering with the table will unleash untold horrors on our world.
- Maybe something with `DCOUNT` or `ARRAYFORMULA`? But those seem to me MORE forbidden than the Necronomicon, not less.

Did try this, but it's just giving me the total number of true values:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(A3:A24,ISEVEN(ROW()),A3:A24,TRUE))`

What else y'all got?

Comment: Not gonna lie, just went cross-eyed trying to think my way through using `QUERY()` to get this done. I'm well stumped.

Comment: Thanks to @MattKing and @doubleunary for the help - between 'em, they steered me straight!

For those keeping track at home, the key thing was to actually declare the range that you wanted to evaluate in the `ROW()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ABS(C3:C-ISEVEN(ROW(C3:C))))
```

UPDATE:
To get the total:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(C3:C-ISEVEN(ROW(C3:C))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Matt's formula looks like the way to go. Try this to get the total:

`=arrayformula( sum( islogical(C3:C) * abs(C3:C - iseven(row(C3:C))) ) )`

Comment: Yup - the backbone of @MattKing's code plus your sum did the trick, though that `ISLOGICAL` broke it a bit...wouldn't it just multiply the `ABS` section by 1 or 0, depending?

Comment: The `islogical()` bit guards against numbers in column C that would throw a spanner in the works.

Comment: @EvangeliusAg Ah, didn't realize you wanted the sum.  yeah, SUMPRODUCT() should do it and obviates the need for Arrayformula...
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(C3:C-ISEVEN(ROW(C3:C))))

Comment: Reading back through the comments, @doubleunary, you got a bonus comment upvote for "spanner."